# Random Playback of lots of short samples

Tags: playback, sample, random

I have about 400 small clips of audio that I would like to play back in random order. The best way I have to try this so far is in iTunes .. I work in Logic and I wondered if anyone has ideas on a way of doing this within logic or any plug ins that do this kind of thing .. The sample are all small clips of electronic music and I want to achieve the effect of a frantic mash up ... Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this software would be of some help: http://soundplant.org/

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy to do in [Ableton with follow actions](https://www.ableton.com/en/blog/clip-launching-and-follow-actions-new-tutorial-dj-tech-tools/), but you can probably get a similar effect in Logic with EXS24.

Load a dozen or so samples into an instance of EXS24, then use Logic's arpeggiator to throw random notes at it. You may need to use multiple instances of EXS24 in order to make use of all 400 of your clips.

Comment: Thanks, I don't use ableton but I have been playing with battery and getting some good effects using the arpeggiator as you described with exs. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In logic you could use the environment window in conjunction with EXS24
https://documentation.apple.com/en/logicpro/usermanual/index.html#chapter=36%26section=0%26tasks=true

Back when I used logic I'd use the environment window to create generative music in much the way people would use Max.